# Adding a Style Sheet to a document using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        /******* Load CSS *******/
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="'+('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +'thesite.com/api/widgets/tghd/pages.css">');    
    });
```

The above code is what I use to add the style sheet to the document. The code inspector shows that the code has been added but the console does not display that the browser has requested the document and the styles do not take affect.

How can I add a style sheet to an already loaded document and have it take affect.

BTW. if it matters, I am using this code for a widget so I will be used across multiple domains.

Thank You in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after doing a few tests, I finally figured out what was going on. This original code was provided by: @Vicky Gonsalves

```
    var li = document.createElement('link');
    li.type = 'text/css';     
    var href=('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +'thesite.com/api/widgets/pages.css';
    li.setAttribute('href', href);
    li.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    s.appendChild(li, s);
```

The changes that I made to this are:

- I added the http and https switch to help with different connection types
- added the attribute li.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet'); <-- which I believe fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
(function () {
    var li = document.createElement('link');
    li.type = 'text/css';     
    var href='http://' + 'thesite.com/api/widgets/tghd/pages.css';
    li.setAttribute('href', href);
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    s.appendChild(li, s);
})();
```

Comment: Hey I tried this, but It is still not working. I can see that the stylesheet is added to the header but it is not being loaded by the browser and the styles are not taking affect.

Comment: I have my browsers cache disabled while in dev, but I also cleared all data and even tried on multiple browsers.